# Alter output of every command

Tags: linux, mac, bash, shell, zsh

I'd like to know if there's any way of altering output of every command I execute in terminal. The purpose is to make the output formated for my markdown howto's.

E.g.

```
ls -la .*z
#>-rw-r--r--  1 hologos  staff   3580 26 zář 14:22 .zconfig
#>-rw-------  1 hologos  staff  28927 17 říj 15:59 .zhistory
#>-rw-r--r--  1 hologos  staff   5600 30 zář 08:03 .zshrc
```

The "#>" is what I want every line of output starts with this.
I primarely use zsh.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like

```
  command | sed -e 's/^/line-prefix /'
```

example

```
$ ls -la m* | sed -e 's/^/#> /'
#> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 76080 Aug 11  2011 mailstats
#> -r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 92824 Aug 11  2011 makemap
#> -rwxr-xr-- 1 root root 12389 Jul 22  2011 makewhatis
#> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11520 Mar  6  2011 matchpathcon
#> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 56600 May 18  2011 mcelog
#> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    15 Mar 18  2011 mkdict -> cracklib-format
#> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9600 Jul 22  2011 mklost+found
#> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10176 Jan  6  2007 mksock
#> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4409 Jan  7  2007 modeline2fb
#> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 23787 Jul 22  2011 mountstats
#> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 58032 Jan  7  2007 mtr
```

You can also apply this to a shell so it is done automatically

```
$ ksh | sed -e 's/^/#> /'
$ ls m*
#> mailstats
#> makemap
#> makewhatis
#> matchpathcon
#> mcelog
#> mkdict
#> mklost+found
#> mksock
#> modeline2fb
#> mountstats
#> mtr
```

There's probably some drawbacks/gotchas, take care with this.

---

A different approach is to run `script` (see `man script`) and then use your favourite editor (or a small perl/awk/etc script) to make it markdown-friendly - In vim I'd just do something like  `:%s/^/#> /` to fix all the lines in one go. Then I'd insert markdown headers etc.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I'm planning on using it while executing all kinds of commands. Are there any drawbacks/gotchas you can think of?

Comment: @Hologos: Some commands behave differently if STDOUT is piped to a process rather than connected to a TTY. Also there's some wierdness with the shell prompting that doesn't seem to cause any harm but which is disconcerting. There's probably more.

Answer (score 1):

```
IFS=$'\n';for line in `ls -la .*z`;do echo "#>$line";done
```

it will loop through command output (`ls -la .*z`) and display the result on the screen by prepending `#>` to every line

ps:

the `IFS` part is for setting the delimiter to **new line** instead of **whitespace**

Comment: Thank you, is there any way I shouldn't have to write this? Something like `cd() { builtin cd "$@" && ll; }` but for every command or some type of alias which would alter every command in the background?

Comment: why would you avoid using the `for` loop?

Comment: Or something like `ls -la .z*` but it would automaticaly expand it as `ls -la .z* | my-program`, which would contain your code.